# Override default TabBarController to show TabBar on not directly referenced via relationship

Tags: swift, xcode, tabs, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I want to use a tab bar at the bottom of my app. But I want it to be used to jump to sections within the app. clicking on a tabBarItem will take you to the first page in a section and on that page will be links that carry you through to the next page(s). in the subsequent pages I still want the tabBar to show at the bottom and I want it to highlight the section that I am in. currently the tabBar disappears when I follow a link to the second page in any group.

I've tried including a tabBarController on each of the subsequent pages and manually setting the tabBar items to match the others and it did show the tabBar on all pages, but it does not highlight which section I am in.

[image: storyboard layout]

Comment: The tab bar controller should be the root view and each tab should have its own navigation controller as the root of the hierarchy of view controllers for that tab.

Comment: thank you, I just had them in the wrong order...doh. this worked great